# In Kubernetes, is there a difference between an ingress router and an application router?

Tags: kubernetes

In Kubernetes, is there a difference between an ingress router and an application router?

I have been learning Kubernetes for a short while, and there is a concept that I am either not able to enunciate specifically enough to get definitive answers while searching, I am incorrect in my assumptions, or the concept is not explained very well.  Here is my thought process:

- A Kubernetes cluster can be the deployment environment for any number of application stacks.
- Each application stack has its own specific routing logic.
- An ingress router seems most appropriate for general environment ingress to application stacks.
- If these assumptions are true, it seems that including a (reverse) proxy in an application stack to provide application-stack-specific routing would be ideal, especially in the sense of separation of concerns and delegation of responsibility in a software system.
- This way, an ingress router can serve as the general entrypoint for each application stack that is hosted in a Kubernetes cluster, without requiring much in the way of configuration.  This is similar to opening ports on a firewall.
- Now the ingress router can simply point the traffic to the specific application stack router for further handling.  All of the logic specific to the application stack is handled here.

I have been trying to see if this is a valid approach or not, but my searches have not given me anything very conclusive.  I would like to start experimenting with this, and use the default ingress router, and then use Traefik as a proxy for the application stack